# Is data binding only used for UI?

Tags: design-patterns, data-binding

I know that data binding is often used for binding between the Views and Models. So it is often used for UIs. However, the same data binding technique could be used in a non-UI context too.

Would binding properties between non-UI classes and objects through data binding acceptable or a bad practice? For example, two plain objects may want to have their properties synchronised. Would using data binding in such scenarios be reasonable and acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really good question.

Generally, I don't see data binding as a form of synchronization. The idea was around for a long time, but what really made it explode is that early attempts to do dynamic web apps were very inefficient. A metrics study from the late 90s showed that a third of programmer time was going into ferreting data from the db onto the form, and then converting the input obtained from the user, and pushing it back into the database. Not long after that, you started to see a lot of frameworks with data binding at their core, like JSF.

If you have objects that need to be synchronized, generally if they have the same structure, then you are just doing what you would when you serialize things: encoding/decoding. If you look at the NSCoding protocol in Objective-C you see a pretty simple approach to this on its face, but one that hides an ingenious design: the coder/decoder just deal in properties, so the entities don't know whether they are being written out as JSON or XML or to a database. You can come into a large project with a huge domain model and add JSON support in an afternoon.

The tendency in the Java world has been to chase the dream of the magical automatic dehydrator/rehydrator. Because Java supports Reflection, the though is, quite naturally: 'hey, I can go get all the properties and write them out, then later, read them back in.' Having done a lot of work with both approaches, I would never do the Reflection one again. Big fan of the encoding protocol approach.

So if your simplest case is just encoding decoding from say, remote to server incarnations (common in mobile apps that have to support shared state in a shared database), then you could just model this as the object being encoded on one side and decoded on the other, and frankly, they could be encoding/decoding in different languages.

Typically synchronization quickly turns into other questions, like 'what if I want to send just the new things?' I did a large mobile app where we did a serious synchronizer and I thought afterwards that I was stunned there were no serious projects to do language agnostic synchronization with all the semantic varieties implied by updates, diffs, versions, etc.

If your graphs are not identical, you will want an Adapter in between. This is another thing that I think makes the argument for encoders quite convincingly because the Adapter has to stand between the two types and perform a mapping, which, like most things, can get very complex. The manipulation of the sides is easier in the encoder scheme than the Reflection one.

One of the interesting things about Adapters is whether you imagine them to be active, or part of a static building process. I tend to think of them as the latter, with the Mediator as the active version of the same thing: two sides that need to be kept ignorant of each other, but must be brought into a scheme of cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

of course it's acceptable. you can find it often in mvc but it's not limited only to UI. e.g. templating. jasper reports use it to generate pdf file, excel etc. spring binds java classes and objects to xml configuration. you can alway do it when compiler can't help you

but i think that concept is explicit only in statically typed languages. when you have no types and you do 'duck typing' this is one big data binding